# Explain query return differents results

Tags: mysql, mariadb-10.1

Data are similar on two servers.

Server A :

```
mysql>  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.26                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1           |
| version                 | 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Server B

```
MariaDB> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+--------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                    |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.42-84.2              |
| protocol_version        | 10                       |
| slave_type_conversions  |                          |
| version                 | 10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 |
| version_comment         | Debian 9.8               |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                   |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu         |
| version_malloc_library  | system jemalloc          |
| version_ssl_library     | YaSSL 2.4.4              |
| wsrep_patch_version     | wsrep_25.24              |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+
```

When I make an EXPLAIN on a query, results are differents :

```
Server A return

+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+----------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type   | possible_keys        | key      | key_len | ref                | rows | filtered | Extra           |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+----------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f1_   | NULL       | index  | IDX_90291C2D2D710CF2 | date_idx | 5       | NULL               |   40 |   100.00 | Using temporary |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u0_   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,closed_idx   | PRIMARY  | 4       | smailsf.f1_.poster |    1 |    50.00 | Using where     |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+--------+----------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+------+----------+-----------------+

Server B return

+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+---------+---------+------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys        | key     | key_len | ref              | rows   | Extra                           |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+---------+---------+------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | f1_   | ALL    | IDX_90291C2D2D710CF2 | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | 657064 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | u0_   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,closed_idx   | PRIMARY | 4       | smail.f1_.poster |      1 | Using where                     |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+----------------------+---------+---------+------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

Why, for the same query, on Server A, number of rows is 40 and Server B, number of rows is 657064 ?

It's like Maria don't considere indexes or cache ?

What kind of configuration options can impact this behaviour ?

Thanks,

Comment: the number of records, DB engine, server zone, indexing, partitioning, keys all these things has to be the same to not see any difference in performance.

Comment: *"And globally, the Server B is slower than Server A.

Why this difference for a same query with same data ?"*  Short answer: Server B is using a older version then Server A, never versions tends to have better optimizers..

Comment: With respect, you have not given us nearly enough information to help you. Please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ and pay special attention to the section on performance. Then please [edit] your question to provide the needed details. And, it's extremely unlikely you will see identical performance on two different servers even for the same data.

Comment: But for better answers you should provide the query on which you run explain on `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in that query... to add to @O.Jones 's comment because this question is relates to performance we need to know datatypes and possible indexes..

Comment: @Ali786, you're right... so I think it's linked to partionning (indexing ?). How can I check partionning difference for example ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

innodb_buffer_pool_size settings is my solution ;) Thanks.